# How to define Javascript function once so that can work after dynamic changes?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

It seems like my script runs only one time and then after invoking another java script function it doesn't get executed till refreshing a page. Of course, I could call this function inside another one, but I don't wanna go this way. I need somehow to define the function so that could execute every time after any dynamic changes. Maybe I need event handler or something like that? Thanks in advance.

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap3-editable/bootstrap-editable
//= require bootstrap-datepicker/core
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require_tree .

 var setXeditable;

$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

setXeditable = function() {
  return $("[data-xeditable=true]").each(function() {
    return $(this).editable({
      ajaxOptions: {
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: "json"
      },
      params: function(params) {
        var railsParams;
        railsParams = {};
        railsParams[$(this).data("model")] = {};
        railsParams[$(this).data("model")][params.name] = params.value;
        return railsParams;
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Use an MVVM framework like Angular or React. They are designed to handle exactly that scenario.

Comment: Are you using turbolinks? Then the javascript is only run once on the initial page load and not on subsequent page requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the function in an [onChange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) method referencing the dynamic field(s).  You can also have it run at a certain [time interval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).